# how to create symbolic link that points to it self - linux

Tags: linux, bash, symlink

Has anyone succeed to create a symbolic link that point to it self?
I tried to create a symlink to some file delete the real file and try to link to it self but got this error:

```
ln: creating symbolic link `********': File exists
```

I know its possible to create this symlink.

Comment: I didn't understand your approach ? Why do you need this, symlink is just a shortcut to the file if real file is deleted the shortcut is meaningless.

Comment: some annyoing bug at some script that make a symlink points to itself and i wanted to recreate the bug.

Comment: @itzikos I was confused for a second why you would ever want to do this. :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can create a symbolic link that points to itself with `ln -s` :

```
$ ln -s testlink testlink

$ ll testlink
lrwxrwxrwx 1 me myGroup 4 19 avr.  11:22 testlink -> testlink
```

However another file with the same name must not exist beforehand :

```
$ touch testlink

$ln -s testlink testlink
ln: impossible de créer le lien symbolique « testlink »: File exists
```

Comment: test is already exist, you are just faking the test, but make a ln -s a b, then remove b then make link to link is that meaningful ? the guy asking this.

Comment: the created link is pointless afaik, but it's still possible to do, which OP asked for. My guess is that he already has a file with the same name.

Comment: I'm not sure but it may be a bug, or something it just there for a low level workaround. When you try to open the file with cat `cat: a: Too many levels of symbolic links` It redirects to itself naturally, I checked the strace output both link created itself and link created based on a real file, no difference, same codes work for them.

Comment: I'm not sure what you expected? When `cat` try to open the file, it will see a link and follow it. Behind that there is a link, which it'll follow too. And again, and again, etc. So yeah, `Too many levels of symbolic links` seems quite alright to me. If you want to see the content of the link rather than the file it points to, you can use `readlink` (or `ls -l`)